# tmux won't start if default shell is fish

Tags: tmux, fish

I have `tmux` and `fish` both installed via `apt` on an Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo).

`tmux` works well out of the box but it uses `bash` and I would like it to use `fish` as default shell.

Thus I put the following line in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
~$ cat .tmux.conf
set-option -g default-shell fish
```

But then `tmux` won't start anymore, instead it prints weird characters and dies:

```
~$ tmux
[exited]
~$ [?65;1;9c
```

(Note: the weird characters are not typed by me, they end up here before my cursor)

Note that if I remove `~/.tmux.conf`
(then `tmux` starts using bash and works well),
I am able to use fish by calling `fish` from `bash`.

Any idea what is happening and how I could solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tmux expects a full path here:

```
set-option -g default-shell /usr/bin/fish
```

(or whatever path your fish is at. See `command -s fish`)

Answer (score 2):

for understanding where your fish binary file is run this code :
`user@user$ which fish`
it should says something like this :
`/usr/bin/fish`

then put these line plus path to end of file `.tmux.conf`:

set -g default-command /path/to/your/fish/

set -g default-shell   /path/to/your/fish/

Answer (score -2):

I'm using docker dev container for development, so I'm using bock TMUX and FISH together, I have defaulted the FISH shell as below when O create the docker image and starts the TMUX from docker ENTRYPOINT.

[This GITHUB repo has related code](https://github.com/mahesh-maximus/mdb/tree/main/tools)